# qgis2threejs export quality of map canvas image

Tags: qgis, export, qgis2threejs, browser

A comparison

qgis2threejs preview: quality near the original within qgis: Very good

browsers chrome+edge: bad (edge a little bit better than chrome)

firefox: extremly bad

What can I do to improve the quality within the browser?
Here the four screenshots as one image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!  I reviewed some of my Qgis2threejs output and I don't see any image quality difference between Firefox, Edge, and Internet Explorer; they all generate identical images.  They are not as crisp as the Qgis2threejs preview, which is expected because I output them at a lower resolution (to speed up web draw time).

Which got me thinking... Is it possible that you generated different output resolutions (image below), and each browser is displaying a different output resolution?  I realize that is a stretch, but I'm trying to think out of the box...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. No. My tests are correct - same export file for all browsers (no cache...). The last 30 min I have do more tests. 4 projects, always with 100,200 and 400%. Always the same (not satisfied) results.

Comment: Do you have a url that you would be willing to share? If so, I would be happy to view them on my browsers as a test.

Comment: I have tested with an openstreetmap image. Here I can see no relevant differences between the browsers, but before with different satellite images. But the main problem exist also in this test: The quality within qgis2threejs preview is more better than with browsers. ( In this time I do no want share files. )